# What makes MQTT a lightweight protocol?

Tags: networking, protocols, mqtt

I have seen that MQTT is said to be a very lightweight protocol. But I couldn't find any detailed information on **what makes MQTT lightweight**. I have seen that this is due to the extremely small overhead in MQTT. My question is how does it achieve a lower overhead.
If anyone could provide me with an answer for this it would be a great help.

Comment: @AydinK. I hope my edit makes it different

Comment: a word 'lightweight' is in IT wide and based on personal sight (and IT marketing too). No sense to analyse in detail, because word is not hard defined (EDIT MQTT probably / really is lightweight, but philosophical discuss have no sense)

Comment: The suggested duplicate question covers everything in your question. It is all to do with how much extra data has to be sent with the actual payload.

Comment: I guess *"lightweight"* means the ratio of *"routing/management data"* to *"useful payload"* is low.